# Java JNA call to C++ dll works from Netbeans but not when .jar is invoked from command line

Tags: java, netbeans-7, jna

My Java program calls a DLL compiled in C++ using JNA. The DLL receives from Java some `int` and `double` values as arguments.
It works fine when run from Netbeans, but when I invoke the Java .jar program from the command line, the C++ program receives rubbish: i.e. an int equal to 1 is received as 64562352. When the program is run repeatedly sending int 1 from Java, the C++ dll receives different numbers: 65631824, 66011704,....

I use Windows 7, Netbeans 7.0.1, Java 1.7.0_01, Microsoft Visual C++ 2008, JNA 3.3.0 (b0).

The relevant code is:

Java:

```
public interface ClibLP extends Library {
    enter code here`public double vectorC (int tipoprob, int nvar, 
                                           double  numero);            
} 

public class LlamadorLP {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {                            
        int tipoprob = 1;
        int nvar = 1000;
        double numero = 1.5;
        double total = clib.vectorC(tipoprob, nvar, numero);     
}
```

C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double  vectorC (int tipoprob, int nvar, 
                                                  double numero);

double  vectorC(int tipoprob, int nvar, double numero) {        
  printf("Estoy en la función C!\n");
  printf("tipoprob=%d\n",tipoprob);
  printf("nvar=%d\n",nvar);
  printf("numero=%6.1f\n",numero);
  return total;
}
```

Many thanks, Mario.

Comment: Examine the JNA versions in both cases (`com.sun.jna.Version.VERSION`).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "Java .jar program". Consider adding the complete command line you use to run it.

Comment: JNA version is 3.3.0 (b0)

Comment: The command line is: java -jar "ProgramPathAndName.jar"

Comment: The JNA library and the Java code is the same in both cases: running from Netbeans and from de command line.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: When called repeatedly from command line, the result of sending an int 1 from Java, is that the int received by the C++ code changes, but not too much: 65631824, 66022704, 65194096,....

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was making a silly Netbeans mistake so there was no trouble with the JNA invocation.

When running from Netbeans I selected the correct class to run. When running from the command line, the .jar used another class as main class so the results were unpredictable. In a word  the dll was called by different classes.
I set the correct main class with Netbeans project properties and everything went righ: both results, running form Netbeans and from the command line are identical.

So JNA is OK.